# login to remote site from my site

Tags: php, curl

I'm building a website and I need to login to another site and take some info from there.
the Problem is that the other site requires a user-name and a password (which I have of course) at it's login page.
How can I enter my user-name & password and then pass to the second page to get the info ?
I'm trying to do it via php but I just read that mayby curl is required..

thanks !

Comment: Related: [PHP Site Scraping With a Secure Login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327908/php-site-scraping-with-a-secure-login)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Login to remote site with PHP cURL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008817/login-to-remote-site-with-php-curl)

Comment: I did search here before posting it, and didn't found any answer but I also didn't see what you posted here.
thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cURL!

Create a page on your remote page that returns the information (i'd recommend using xml as your format) that you want then grab it like this from the site requesting information.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.yourRemoteWebsite.com/mysecretinformation.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username=Roee84&password=yourPassword');

$myInfo = curl_exec($ch)
```

At that point, `$myInfo` will have whatever information you sent from the other side.

if you end up using xml, check out http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php for easy parsing.