# Getting access to the protected page when shouldn't

Tags: php, curl

Ok, so my problem is that I have a page which requires $_SESSION['loggedIn'] to be true and if it's not, than i'm redirecting to login page. Everything works fine, except that when I tried to get access to this page with simplest cURL:

```
    $url2 = 'http://localhost/page/which/requires/session_variable';

    $ch = curl_init($url2);
    curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,        false); 
    curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,        true); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $result;
```

I got the content of the page. How Can I fix that?

Comment: What do you mean? You get the content from that page even though it checks for `$_SESSION['loggedin']`? Did you check that the session variable isn't set?

Comment: yes, exactly. When I set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to 'true' than i'm redirected to login page, but when i don't i get the content of page even though i'm not logged in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Site Scraping With a Secure Login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327908/php-site-scraping-with-a-secure-login)

Comment: What does the code on the actual page where you check for this session variable look like?

Comment: @Jon it's not that. They're writing about logging in and after that getting data. I get the data without logging.

There is a function which checks: if($_SESSION['loggedIn'] != true) { header("Location: ".URL. 'CMS/'); }

Comment: @user2768251: It is not the same on the surface, but it's the same under the hood. In both cases the server initializes a session for you and sends you a cookie. You need to present that cookie on further `curl` requests, and by the looks of it you *also* need to login. Unless I have misunderstood "I got the content of the page". Which page? What did you want to get instead?

Comment: @Jon so what I'm supposed to do? Getting any cookie/session data is not changing anything with curl redirect when I set 'followlocation' to 'false'. You are speaking a little bit too general and I don't get what should I do.

let's say i have a page 'CMS/newses' - when I'm not logged in ( $_SESSION['loggedIn'] is false ) i'm redirected to CMS/login. But when I use cURL to get data of the page ( 'CMS/newses' ) I get it. It's not very secure as You can guess, but I don't know how to block it in any way.

Comment: @user2768251: So your problem is that *you are getting access to the protected page when you should not*. Wouldn't that be a better title for the question? In any case, you should give the code that sets `$_SESSION['loggedin']` at the very least.

Comment: sorry for misleading title. Fixed. But my problem not :P i set $_SESSION variable after verification if this is what You meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CURL will ignore the header directive and move on if the script doesn't stop at that stage.

Return a 403 forbidden as an else clause and `die()` or `exit()` immediately afterwards, after failing the isLoggedIn check and CURL will no longer get access.

Comment: If i put 'header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden"); die('No permission');' than it is working, but it is not the way i'm looking for. Or is the only solution to put into "die()" clause my login page?

Comment: Yes. U need to add die() or exit; after your `header('Location: ....'); ` This is good practise

Comment: @user2768251, Yes, you need to explicitly indicate script termination, otherwise it will cough up the remaining content regardless of header code.

Comment: Ok, so the last question ( thank You guys very much ) - die() after Location or header(403) and die() with login page? I mean I'm looking for solution which is approved by society ;)

Comment: @user2768251, Right after you return the 403 code. If the user is on a browser, he'll get redirected before that happens, and any CLI solutions will kick the bucket before they get to the restricted parts.